# Migrating assembly code from 32 to 64 bit question

Tags: 64-bit, operating-system, intel, 32-bit

I'm responsible for some application level code that I inherited that has some x86... Intel assembly code based on 32 bit instructions and addressing. I going to make the assumption this 32 bit assembly code will run when we migrate a 64 bit windows OS. Yes?

Comment: This is embedded in C++ code.

Comment: Why the close votes, I wonder.

Comment: Perhaps this will not be as easy as I thought. I got link from a responder (sorry - not sure who as this question moved)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb5z4sxd.aspx

That states "Inline ASM is not supported for x64. Use MASM or compiler intrinsics (x64 Intrinsics)."

Answer (score 2):

It will probably run, but it won't take advantage of any of the features the 64-bit extensions to x86 asm provide (x86-64, which is what all "64-bit" versions of Windows are) or be able to tightly interop with x64 libraries. The WoW64 layer is very stable and 99.999% of 32-bit apps run fine on current "64-bit" OSes.

If you want to migrate to a true 64-bit operating system (the only ones I know of are Itanium-based, ia64), you're out of luck.

Edit: Also, if you want to enable large-address access (able to use >4gb of RAM), there's a PE header flag you can flip that will turn that on and allow it to address larger amounts of memory.

Comment: Fantastic! Many Thanks! I'm new here (but have a good standing on SO) wish I had a good enough reputation here so I could give a vote up.

Comment: Same. I'm not worried about rep so voting doesn't matter, but if I answered it for you, you might want to accept just so folks know. :)

Comment: Ok will accept, but it's not obvious how to do that (at least to me). Send FAQ link :-)

Comment: I'll upvote this - you bothered to be more technical than I did. :)

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, it will run; 64-bit Windows supports 32-bit mode for applications and it's generally very reliable.  (Obviously these things are never 100%, though - caveat emptor.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 32-bit code will run on 64-bit machines, but they won't be able to access more than 4 GiB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

It will *run* if you continue to build 32-bit x86 applications, yet. However if you have to port the code to 64-bit x86, chances are that the assembly code won't run (and might not even compile) out of the box.

And depending on your tool chain and if it's inline assembler in C/C++ code or not, you might not even be able to compile it at all.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Not even compile? It's embedded C++ code.

Comment: From memory - at least with the MS compiler, inline assembler will simply not compile on the 64-bit toolchain as the compiler doesn't support `__asm`. I don't know if other compilers like GCC suffer from this problem as well.

Comment: We are using VS - probably 2010 by the time the code transfer takes place. I am so not looking forward to re-writing assy code, not impossible for me, but not a task I signed up for.

Comment: I haven't got my hands on VS2010 yet, but from this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb5z4sxd.aspx it looks like you're up the creek - no inline asm on 64 bit, although you can still use MASM for larger chunks.